# What are the stat boosts gained when raid Shadow Pokemon become enraged, and how much do Purified Gems lower them?

Tags: pokemon-go

Technically two questions in one, but they are closely related.

I just attempted a three-star Shadow Quilava raid. I had depleted half of its health in less than 60 seconds. Then it became enraged, and ended taking significantly less damage. As a ball-park figure from looking at its health (all my estimates are ball-park figures), only taking 10-20% of what it was previously, far less than what I would have guessed, and dealing about 200% more damage. After battling it for another 30 seconds and realising that continuing like this would have been futile, I attempted using two purified gems, with break of about 20 seconds in between them. They did seem to lower its defence and attack in the battle, but not by much (about 10-20% for defence per gem, about 25% per gem). I ended up failing this battle, which would have been a trivial victory without the Shadow enrage factor.

To better plan for future Shadow raids, I wish to know:

- What are the exact figure boosts provided by becoming enraged to Attack and Defence?
- How much do these boosts get lowered by Purified Gems?

All the sources online only seem to state increases and decreases without figures, and many do not seem to reflect how huge these increases actually are.

Answer (score 5):

Not a complete answer, but it addresses question 2. The Purified Gems only have an effect if eight are used in a raid battle. It removes the enraged effect and its boosts. If any less than eight are used, the boosts remain unchanged.

Of note, a single player can only use up to five Purified Gems in a battle. This means that when attempting to solo a Shadow raid, the Purified Gems have no effect. Save the Gems for raids alongside other players.